# Scope issue in recursive Javascript function

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope

I have a recursive function (performing [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) to generate permutations). It seems to have a variable scope issue.

```
function permute(starting_arr) {
  var all_permutations = [];
  heap(starting_arr, starting_arr.length-1);
  console.log(all_permutations);
  return all_permutations;

  function heap(a, n) {  // a = array, n = max index i.e. length -1
    var temp_an;

    if (a.length-1 == n) {
      all_permutations.push(a); 
    }

    if (n>1) {
      heap(a.slice(), n-1);
    }

    for ( var i=0; i<n ; i++ ) {
      temp_an = a[n];
      if (n%2==0) {
        a[n] = a[0]
        a[0] = temp_an;
      } else {
        a[n] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp_an; 
      }

      all_permutations.push(a); 

      if (n>1) { heap(a.slice(), n-1); }   
    }
  }
}
```

It seems the problem is the "all_permutations.push(a)" because the thing works if I replace that with ...

```
 all_permutations.push([]); 
 for ( var g=0 ; g<a.length ; g++ ) {
   all_permutations[all_permutations.length-1][g] = a[g];
 }
```

And as you can see I'm trying to use slice, which I've read about as a solution allowing you to pass the array by value rather than reference, such as in this ...

```
function x(arr){
  arr.push(4);
}

var a = [1,2,3]
x(a);
console.log(a);
var b = [1,2,3]
x(b.slice());
console.log(b);
```

That does something but it still doesn't work properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, it's not a scope problem. You're just not copying the array in the right places.

Comment: Thanks to @bergi's help, it works now.Here's here as a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/teecoo/a7uzqxbh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as you can see I'm trying to use slice, which I've read about as a solution allowing you to pass the array by value rather than reference

Yes, you found the problem and the correct approach for solving it. However you need to specifically apply it to the line

```
all_permutations.push(a);
```

in your `for` loop:

```
all_permutations.push(a.slice());
```